# Understand application architecture

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, architecture

I am a S/W developer working on a Java web application.

I have very limited knowledge of Java and want to understand my application architecture from a very high level in simple terms. Being a developer, I do not completely understand the big picture.

Can anyone help me understand this?

[image: Below is the arch image]

Comment: You forgot to attach the pic, but are you sure this is a good idea? Architecture diagrams are usually company secret!

Comment: i have linked the image now...

Comment: I saw one of these at the SNCB/NMBS (national railroads company in Belgium). It offers some insights into how applications are built. Very interesting.

Comment: Do u have any reference for the same?

Comment: As Enno said, these diagrams are sometimes secret and I don't work for this company. You can find a few examples on Google image though with the keywords architecture diagram software. http://www.google.com/search?q=architecture+diagram+software&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&hl=fr&tab=wi&biw=1057&bih=764

Comment: Design patterns refer to class scope solutions that solve problems related to object creation, object interaction and object communication.  Architecture is at a level above design pattern scope while functional solutions are a level below design pattern scope and relate to algorithms.  I am retagging your question.

Answer (score 2):

Each layer represents a place where some problems are solved is similar way, often using some particular libraries or frameworks. In trying to understand this work your way down through the layers. BUT, note that each layer hides the details underneath, you don't need to understand the details of lower layers in order to understand one layer.

So the Struts piece is dealing with the User-Interface related issues of understanding user requests choosing some business logic to invoke and choosing how to display the results back to the user. It doesn't concern itself with **how** the business logic works, that's the job of the next layer down.

By Business Logic I mean the Java (or other language) code that expresses the realities of a the customer's business. For example in a retail application we might need to work out discounts for particular volumes of orders. So the UI layer wants to display the price for a customer's order. It doesn't have any discount logic itself, instead it says to the business logic layer "Customer X is order N widgets and M zettuls, when can we supply and how much shall we charge" and the business logic figures out the pricing for this customer, which might depend on all sorts of things such as the status of the customer, the number things we have in stock, the size of the order and so on. The UI just gets an answer *£450, to be delivered 16th September*, and displays it.

That leads to questions such as "why separate the business logic to its own layer?" There are several possible reasons:

- The business logic might be used  by some completely different UI as well
- It pre-exists, from some older system
- Our brains are too small to think about UI and Business Logic at the same time
- We have different teams working on UI and BL - different skills are needed

This same way of thinking follows down the layers. Th important thing when thinking about each layer is to try to focus on the role of the layer and treat the other layers as black-boxes. Our brains tend to be too small to think about the whole thing at the same time. I can almost feel myself changing mode as I shift between the layers - take off my UI head, put on my persistence head.

There's plenty of material "out there" about each layer. Suggest you start by reading up about one of them and ask specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: When u say business logic, r u referring to theactual Java code?

Comment: Think of the operations and algorithms that can be carried out on data. This is of a different nature from the logic that is used to get data (Data Access Layer) or to present it (Presentation Layer or UI).

Comment: added further explanation of business logic in the answer. It's quite likely that every layer here is written in Java - doesn't have to be, but reading the diagram I guess it is in this case.

Comment: Cool..thx a lot..things seem much clearer now..a few questions before i close..u say business logic It pre-exists, from some older system...that is true, we do have a legacy system as well..but how did u come to know from the arch diagram?..Also any info about the Model from the arch?

Comment: @djna: did u get the notification for above?

Comment: Frankly, I'm calling on years of experience with such systems I didn't look a the diagram that closely. In the real world there are very few truly "Green Field" developments, where everything is new - there's nearly always legacy. In this case though the diagram does have a clue to one such legacy: there's a Service Gateway and a box labelled Existing Systems. It's also possible that some of the Core Services or other Application Services may pre-exist - you can't tell that from this diagram.

Comment: Ok..Just one last question...Is the MVC thing at the overall arcnitecture level OR only at the Presentation tier/level as seen in the diagram above..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a standard "enterprisy" application to me.

#### Interface

This app. is primarily intended to be used via web browsers by humans. This interface or UI layer (in a broad sense) is build using the MVC framework Struts. If you don't know MVC, then it's a good idea to read up on this term.

The app. also exposes web service interface, which is intended to be used by non-humans (other applications or scripts).

So, 2 kinds of interface is provided.

#### Business logic

Request coming from the 2 interfaces noted above, ultimately talk to the lower half (App. tier) to get some real job done. The actual process (calculating stuff, storing stuff and what not) happens here. Note also that this tier also talks to external systems (via Service Gateway) in order to complete the requests.

The reason they separated the system like this can vary. If it's a very simple, small app. then it doesn't pay off to have these abstractions, so it's probably a quite complex system. Maybe the app. tier is some legacy app. and they wanted to put some better UI on top of it. Maybe the app. tier and the web tier happened to use different technology stack. Or perhaps the app. tier is used by many other external systems. It also makes updating each services/replacing each services etc. easier, so maybe they are anticipating that. Anyways, it looks like a very common SOA type of design.

Not sure what else you might want to know. I see that the designer intends to use distributed cache in both tiers. All in all, it's a very common type of system integration diagram.

Comment: Thx a lot for the explanation..What exactly would u. Mean by web tier or app tier ? I'll have a few more questions as well...

Comment: Web tier and application tier as in the context of an n-tier/multitier architecture: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture

Answer (score 0):

App Tier - Where the basic application logic resides (think of a basic console-only program).

- **Database** - MySQL, Oracle... server
- **DOs** - Short for Domain Objects. If anemic usually limited to getters/setters and can be synonymous with Entities (@Entity).
- **Data Access Objects** - Objects using DAO pattern to fetch domain objects from the database. Could be considered equivalent as DAL (Data Access Layer) although this might not fit here. Usually uses a persistence/mapping framework such as Hibernate or iBatis.
- **Domain Model** - Where Domain (domain being what has been studied/analyzed from requirements) Classes are packaged and associated (one-to-one, many-to-one, ...). Sometimes there are even composited in other container classes.
- **Core Application Services** - Groups Services classes which could be equated to the Business Logic Layer (BLL). Biz services handle the Domain Model, Application Services are relative to the Application (methods don't manipulated Domain) and not sure what System Services are supposed to do. I'm also not sure what the distinction between Core and the  Application Service block is.
- **Facade/Interface** - This is where all the communication is done with other Tiers. It helps to fully understand interfaces and the Facade pattern.
- **TOs**: Transfer Objects. Related to Domain Objects and used for transferring as the name implies.

Web Tier - All the logic added to make the application accessible from the Web.

- **Business Delegate**: Block using delegation pattern? Here it apparently plays the middle man between Application facade and the Presentation Tier using TOs.
- **Model**: Notion relative to the MVC pattern and variants. With JSF I know that beans are usually linked to JSPs. This model is to be distinguished from the Domain Model. It is created for the purposes of presentation and might contain information that has nothing to do with the data being manipulated in the application tier and is specific to the web tier.
- **View**: Notion relative to the MVC pattern and variants. JSPs represent individual pages and use their own markup.
- **Session**: Look up theory on sessions (necessary as HTTP is stateless).
- **ApplicationContext**: Groups instances/settings that can be pulled into from anywhere. Often associated in the Java world with the Spring framework. To not be confused with UglyGlobalVar/singletons.
- **Front controller**: Could be considered as equivalent to Controller of MVC although the Front Controller pattern appears to be more specific. Servlets are considered as controllers as they handle communication (GET, POST...) and coordinate the model/view. Not familiar with Struts but imagine that the framework implements classes to represent user actions.
- **Presentation Tier**: Simply all of the logic used for outside presentation.
- **Filters**: Can be used to filter requests, for example to redirect a request to a login page.

Feel free to add/correct this description.